# Updating packages policy

Tags: packaging

I need to use libvirt 8.10+ and as it is right now - I'm compiling it from sources, but my solution is far from being perfect (I had to disable apparmor for instance), I would love to install it from repository instead. Does anyone know, if Ubuntu 23.04 may receive it (right now it has libvirt 8.6 - same as Ubuntu 22.10) or new version of package will be added in next release - 23.10?

Comment: lunar-proposed (23.04) currently is testing libvirt 9.0.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to request an update to a package, by filing a bug at [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvirt/+bugs) as per the sync [request process](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SyncRequestProcess) however according to the [release schedule](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/lunar-lobster-release-schedule/27284) at  it's Feature Freeze and Debian Import Freeze tomorrow, 23rd Feb. So you may be a little late.

Comment: Thank you so much, it was very useful answer.